# How to loop in firestore in a map with flutter?

Tags: loops, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore called `Videos` in  it will be 100 maps named from 1 to 100 contains `Uploader` and `Link` fields, what I want is to get each map and make a list for links and another list for uploaders, I need some help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdk9U.jpg)

Comment: Like What code ??

Comment: tried loop but couldn't figure a logic to enter every map which is numbered from 1 to 100

Comment: see edit above .

Comment: I recommend you to check this link: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem, for help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's important to include as much details and an effort of researching as much as possible and don't ask just for someone else to code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model from this;

```
 return StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Videos').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,  AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link']));
              },
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
```

Comment: ok good but what about the `i`, How am I gonna add 1 to the i after every time ??

Comment: It returned this error : `Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: length`

Comment: documents is not defined

Comment: `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#9e0c4 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT` :(

Comment: why it says it needs paint()

Comment: where to put it ?

Comment: Last thing XD : `A build function returned null.`